# Can I install Bootstrap v4.6 with cssbundling-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, cssbundling-rails

I have a Rails 6.1 app with the `cssbundling-rails` and `jsbundling-rails` apps.
This is an upgraded app using the asset pipeline.

I need to use bootstrap version 4.6, not latest bootstrap v5.
But `rails css:install:bootstrap` installs v5.

--UPDATE--

I changed bootstrap to version `^4.6` in package.json, removed bootstrap-icons and ran `yarn install`.

The problem is my original application.scss isn't loading, the application.debug  in the browser tools only includes bootstrap.